# write.table extra column

Tags: r

In the following data.frame there are 6 columns, but 7 are written to
the CSV file. Can't figure out why.

```
install.packages("pmlr")
library(pmlr)
data(enzymes)
write.table(enzymes, sep=",", eol="\n",file="albert.csv")
```

Answer (score 17):

This question is better suited to StackOverflow. In any case, the problem is that R by default writes the row names. To write only the data itself, use

```
 write.table(enzymes, sep=",", eol="\n", file="albert.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```